# Do states still have to redraw districts even if reapportionment doesn’t affect them?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, voting-districts, redistricting

The US census has been completed last year and is currently being processed. As a result, states will gain/lose/hold electoral votes and hence members of their congressional delegation. Do states still have to redraw their districts if this number stays the same?

Comment: Do you mean whether they have to **redraw** the districts, i.e. they _must_ make a change, or whether they have to **re-evaluate** the lines, i.e. check _if_ they need to make a change? I would assume you're asking about the latter, no?

Comment: Yes the latter. Where, if the # of districts remain, do they still get redrawn.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Generally, yes. Even when a state keeps the same number of congressional districts, people might have moved around the state. Districts have to all be approximately equal in population, so when the new census figures come out the state has to make sure that they're still approximately equal. If they're not, the state has to change them so they are.

Comment: The obvious exception being those states (AK, DE, MT, ND, SD, VT, WY) that have only one Representative.